# Importing a message from the phone to an App

Tags: android, import, message

Hi I would like from my App to be capable of importing a text message from a contact on the phone and make it into a string. I was wondering if that could be possible in any way? I have tried looking for an answer to it, but dont seem to find any. Hope someone can help me with it :)

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What do you mean by "a message"?
A text message? an MMS? an app-specific event message?

Comment: a text message from a contact on the phone

Comment: I can see why you'd ask the question, since it relies using undocument content providers (`content://sms/`) but there are a lot of examples out there on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
//this class will hold our sms information
public class Sms
{
   public String Id;
   public String Address;
   public String Readstate;
   public String Message;
   public String Time;

   public Sms(string id, string address, string message, string readstate, string time)
   {
      Id = id;
      Address = address;
      Message = message;
      Readstate = readstate;
      Time = time;
   }
}
```

This function can retreive all SMS messages in a folder on the user's phone.

The folders are just the basic ones you would expect when dealing with SMS messages ("Inbox", "Sent", etc)

```
//gets all sms messages in a specific folder in the user's sms messages
public List<Sms> getAllSms(String folderName) 
{
    //initiate a new ArrayList to put our messages in
    //ArrayLists are basically arrays on steroids (this is basic Java stuff)
    List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();

    //The SMS object is somewhere in the Android SDK.
    //your IDE should be able to resolve where to find it for you.
    Sms objSms = new Sms();

    //find the SMS messages on the phone in the directory we want
    //using android's content resolver
    Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/"+folderName);
    ContentResolver cr = mActivity.getContentResolver();

    //initiate a Cursor object that will help us iterate through the result set
    Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
    mActivity.startManagingCursor(c);
    int totalSMS = c.getCount();

    //if we can find a message in this result set:
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        //iterate through all the messages in our result set
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {
            //retrieve the contents of this message and put them in "our" Sms object
            objSms = new Sms(
              c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")), //retrieve Id, crash if Id cannot be found
              c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")), //retreive address, crash if it cannot be found
              c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")), //retreive message content,  crash if it cannot be found
              c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")), //retreive whether message is read or not
              c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")) //retreive message date, crash if it cannot be found
            );
            lstSms.add(objSms);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    //optionally, you can uncomment the following code to have error handling
    //for empty sms folders:
    // else {
    // throw new RuntimeException("You have no SMS in " + folderName);
    // }

    //close the cursor and free up resources
    c.close();

    //return the sms files we found in the directory
    return lstSms;
}
```

You can then retreive messages like this:

```
    List<Sms> inboxMessages = getAllSms("inbox"); // Get all sms from inbox
    List<Sms> sentMessages = getAllSms("sent"); // Get all sms from sent
```

Comment: Take note, that the sms content provider in these examples is not documented. your mileage may vary.

Comment: I am not completely sure about how the code above works (am a little new to programming), could you try to explain it a little? :)

Comment: Furthermore does it look like it finds all SMS, but I am looking for a way to make the user choose which SMS he/she wants to import and use in the APP.

Comment: This would be a good starting point to let the user choose which sms he/she wants, right? ;) the rest should be peanuts. i'll add some more comments so you can tell what does what

Comment: Just a last thing :P The folderName what is that? sorry if stupid question, but cant seem to figure it out :P

Comment: it's just "inbox" or "sent" (i've updated my example for you)

Comment: So this code... creates a list... then look through one contact person at a time for messages and set each of the messages in the list one by one? am I correct? but im still a little fuzzy about the folderName... should i just write folderName in the final code? or should i write something else where there stand it.. like "Peter" or another contact person? btw thx for all the help so far :)

Comment: There is also an error at every place where there stands Sms :P

Comment: mActivity should i write the name of my current activity there? :)

Comment: Yes, you can request ContentResolvers from any instantiated activity.

Comment: Looks like i made a little mistake ; the SMS class isn't part of the SDK, you'd have to write it yourself.

Comment: I updated the answer again, it now contains an example Sms class and the `getAllSms` function has been updated to use it.